# What happen when we define two classes with same name in CSS file?

Tags: css

Suppose I define two classes in a CSS file with the same name, like

```
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif/*{ffDefault}*/;
    font-size: 1.1em/*{fsDefault}*/;
}

.ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Actually I found this code in a [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) file. Why are there two classes? What is the difference if we write it like the following?

```
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif/*{ffDefault}*/;
    font-size: 1.1em/*{fsDefault}*/;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.ui-widget .ui-widget` will only apply on the `.ui-widget` element which is by itself nested in another `.ui-widget` element.

E.g.

```
<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        The style will NOT be applied on this element.

        <div class="ui-widget">
            The style will be applied on this element.

            <div class="ui-widget">
                And here also, etcetera.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: HHmm you mean to say that `.ui-widget {..}` apply to only `<div class="ui-widget">The style will NOT be applied on this element.`. But `.ui-widget .ui-widget {..} `. apply to `<div class="ui-widget">
The style will be applied on this element.` and all the elements that are inside the ` <div class="ui-widget">` and also has a class `ui-widget`. Am i right?

Comment: You asked about `.ui-widget .ui-widget` style. I answered about `.ui-widget .ui-widget` style. The `.ui-widget` style applies (obviously) on ALL `.ui-widget` elements.

Comment: Thanks to you all. This is parent child relationship.. OK:)

Answer (score 0):

The second one represents an element with the class `ui-widget` **somewhere inside another** element with the class `ui-widget`. They're not the same selector.

```
<div class="ui-widget"> <!-- font-size: 1.1em -->
    <div class="ui-widget"> <!-- font-size: 1em -->
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="ui-widget"> <!-- font-size: 1em -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write as follows, parent and child both elements will effect from same properties.

```
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif/*{ffDefault}*/;
    font-size: 1.1em/*{fsDefault}*/;
    font-size: 1em;
 }
```

but

```
.ui-widget {
   font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif/*{ffDefault}*/;
   font-size: 1.1em/*{fsDefault}*/;
}

.ui-widget .ui-widget {
     font-size: 1em;
}
```

will follow only parent and child.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply jQuery UI style, the result will be:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    Text with font-size 1.1em
    <div class="ui-widget">
        Text with font-size 1em
        The style will be applied with ".ui-widget .ui-widget" selector
    </div>
</div>
```